# RecyclerView при нажатии на конкретный элемент открывается другой RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Есть фрагмент содержащий RecyclerView который содержит изображения. При нажатии на какое нибудь изображение открывается Activity тоже содержащий RecyclerView с изображениями и при нажатии на один из элементов открывается ListView, основанное на пред идущем выборе.

**Как можно это реализовать?**

- Например: суп - виды супов - рецепт;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то реализовать это можно например следующим образом. У вас например есть три активити A-B-C. Это я например говорю, чтобы было проще понять. Вот на активити A  у вас есть самые глобальные переменные, например `суп`. Дальше это значит в числе этих глобальных переменных есть и другие виды блюд, например какое-нибудь `мясо`. Вот вы при нажатии на ваш `суп` должны на следующее активити передавать переменную которая содержит информацию о том что был выбран именно суп и программе нужно заполнить список на активити B именно видами супов а не видами мяса. Дальше та же ситуация - вы выбираете вид вашего супа и при выборе передаете переменную на активити С которая будет содержать рецепт именно того вида супа который вы выбрали на активити B.

Передача данных с одной активити на другую делается очень просто при помощи интентов. Где вы будете брать данные я не очень понял, но все-равно будет это сервер, или локальная бд, запрос к ней или к нему будет основан на том что будете передавать с каждой активити. С фрагментов тоже можно передавать значения, и на активити тоже.

Возможно я не очень правильно описал решение вашей задачи, если у кого-то будет более изящное решение проблемы, то мне будет интересно с ним ознакомится. Надеюсь хоть чем-то вам помог. Удачи :)